# Is it possible to use n-tier architecture with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, n-tier-architecture

Is it possible to use n-tier such as business entity, business logic, data access in ASP.NET MVC? Is it efficient to use n-tier in MVC?

Comment: Yes it's possible, however unless your business scenario demands it, I wouldn't call n-tier efficient. I'd definitely not recommend it as your first step into MVC.

Comment: yes.. MVC internally divided in tier UI and BI( Business intelligence - controls).. check this according to architecture [Architecture Guide: ASP.NET MVC Framework + N-tier + Entity Framework and Many More](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP_NET_MVC_WITH_EF.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ASP.NET MVC lends itself quite naturally to creating tiered architectures.  Presentation and UI logic implemented by views and view-models can be connected by controllers to business logic and entities below, which in turn can be serviced by a data layer.

Answer (score 0):

n-tier is technically 3 or more tiers.  Based on best patterns and practices, you can see projects like "Silk" that contain multiple projects in the solution.  You can leverage a WCF project that you consume soap objects or restful resources within mvc.  Whether you use Entity Framework or not, I suggest a repository pattern and keep business logic out of the repositories.

Keep logic out of controllers, repositories and have a SOC (separation of concerns).  Try to look into the SOLID principle.  This is where you can start to break things down into manageable and maintainable pieces of code.